# Deserialize .json in .netcore from firebase (Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]))

Tags: c#, json, firebase, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a JSON with this format:

```
{"-LIbdaC_Vye-c4eNCxUs":
[
{"area":"XXXXXX","cargo":"XXXXX XXXXX","data_de_admissao":"XXXXXXXX","matricula":"XXXXXX","nome":"XXXXXXX","salario_bruto":"XXXXXXXXX"},
{"area":"XXXXXX","cargo":"XXXXX XXXXX","data_de_admissao":"XXXXXXXX","matricula":"XXXXXX","nome":"XXXXXXX","salario_bruto":"XXXXXXXXX"},
{"area":"XXXXXX","cargo":"XXXXX XXXXX","data_de_admissao":"XXXXXXXX","matricula":"XXXXXX","nome":"XXXXXXX","salario_bruto":"XXXXXXXXX"}]}
```

And this classe:

```
 public class Funcionario
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "area", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Area { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cargo", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Cargo { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data_de_admissao", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string DataAdmissao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "matricula", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Matricula { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nome", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "salario_bruto", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string SalarioBruto { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate the class with the JSON data, which is a list of objects

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(teste);
var list = new List<Funcionario>();
foreach (var itemDynamic in data)
{
    list.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Funcionario>(((JProperty)itemDynamic).Value.ToString()));
}
```

Instead of picking up an element from JSON it rescues the whole JSON.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
```

I always get this error, all the solutions I saw here did not work for this type of JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the wrapping object you would need to use a dictionary.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Funcionario>>>(teste);

List<Funcionario> list = data.First().Value;
```